# Flask não espera retorno da função para mostrar a view

Tags: python, flask

Tenho uma função que retorna valores para serem mostrados na view. Nos testes em localhost funciona perfeitamente, o servidor espera o retorno dessa função e só então apresenta os dados na tela.

O problema é que quando faço o deploy no Heroku, o servidor não espera esse retorno da função e mostra o retorno vazio. Já tentei com várias opções, *threading*, *concurrent.futures*, todas funcionam localmente, mas não funcionam quando faço o deploy.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
        future = e.submit(get_movie_players, soup)
        links_list = future.result()

        movie_data.append({'name':movie_name,
        'cover': movie_cover[0].replace(');',''),
        'thumbnail': movie_thumb,
        'sinopsys': sinopys,
        'date': movie_date,
        'duration': movie_duration,
        'links': links_list})
```

No exemplo, a variável *links_list* em localhost tem o resultado da *future*, mas é vazio quando faço deploy.

Answer (score 1):

já que você tem que esperar o retorno da função aí, o mais simples é __não usar_  concurrent.futures, nem threads - simplesmente faça `links_list = get_movie_players(soup)`.

O uso dessas estratégias de chamadas em paralelo é justamente útil quando você não precisa aguardar o retorno de uma função.

Você não tem absolutamente *nenhum* ganho com esse desenho. Como é uma aplicação web, o que vai cuidar do paralelismo para você, para a aplicação poder responder a mais de um pageview de uma vez é o servidor wsgi  -  numa configuração manual você escolhe uwsgi, gunicorn, ou algum outro. O Heroku usa o dele.

De qualquer forma, a chamada a `result()` sem passar um timeout, deveria esperar a execução em paralelo - o que acontece é que você deve estar esbarrando em limites de processo da sua conta no heroku - não lembro os termos de serviços deles, mas é muito provável que a conta grátis limite os processos, e talvez até as threads, que você possa disparar - quem controla threads e processos é o servidor wsgi (que nesse caso está sob controle do Heroku, não o seu).

Se precisar realmente paralelizar as chamadas aí - (isso é, um único ageview vai mostrar o resultado de scrapping de várias páginas), vai precisar redesenhar toda a aplicação - para retornar um html "esqueleto", e passar os resultados asíncronos para a página web usando alguma técnica assíncrona (chamadas ajax, desenvolvimento com react, etc)..